# C - Incrementing not working after break statement

Tags: c, for-loop, increment, break, short

Why does this not work?

```
short pStringCt = 0;
const char* constInBuf = ibuf;
int j;
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    /*Detect when there's a space in the buffer and grab word*/
    if (ibuf[j] == ' ' ||
        ibuf[j] == '|' ||
        j == i - 1)
        {
            int k;
            for (k = j - 1; k >= 0; k--){

                if (k == 0 || ibuf[k] == ' ' || ibuf[k] == '|')
                {
                    if (pStringCt > 0){
                        pString[pStringCt] = strndup(constInBuf + k + 1, j - k + 1);
                        printf("-pString at %d is: %s\n", pStringCt, pString[pStringCt]);
                        pStringCt += 1;
                    }
                    if (pStringCt == 0){
                        pString[pStringCt] = strndup(constInBuf+k, j-k + 1);
                        printf("-----pString at %d is: %s\n", pStringCt, pString[pStringCt]);
                        pStringCt+=1;
                    }
                    printf("%d is pStringCt\n", pStringCt);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The value of pStringCt is not incrementing after the break statement. In other words, pStringCt is 0 to begin with at the start of the method. Then, it increases to one after the two if statements pertaining to it. But after the break statement, it resets to zero...

Comment: Have you thought of debugging your program?

Comment: I have and did. The printf statements always give me back 0 before the increment, and 1 after the increment. But they never start at 1 and give back 2, etc..

Comment: please paste the whole code and give us a output of your current code.I see there is a lot of print there,you can simply debug your code by printing the value before the first statement right after the break statement.

Answer (score 1):

So I was using scanf to get my string, which iterated through my method of getting my string twice, which messed up the return value of the method. Sorry for not pasting all of the code, but I just answered my own question...sorry...

P.S. Using getline() now. Works like a charm.